# Kaniko do not use cache options

Tags: build, gitlab, gitlab-ci, kaniko

I am trying to use the --cache-repo option of the kaniko executor but I see that it does not use the cache that I saved in ECR/AWS and the gitlab log returns this;

```
Checking for cached layer [MASKED]/dev-cache:627d56ef7c151b98c02c0de3d3d0d9a5bc8d538b1b1d58632ef977f4501b48f4...
INFO[0521] No cached layer found for cmd COPY --from=build /../../../../..............
```

I have rebuilt the image with the same tag and the code has not changed and it is still taking the same time...

The version of kaniko I am using is the following gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.9.1

These are the flags I use in kaniko:

```
  /kaniko/executor --cache=true \
    --cache-repo "${URL_ECR}/dev-cache" \
    --cache-copy-layers \
    --single-snapshot \
    --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" ${BUILD_IMAGE_EXTRA_ARGS} \
    --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile" \
    --destination "${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}" \
    --destination "${IMAGE_NAME}:latest" \
    --skip-unused-stages \
    --snapshotMode=redo \
    --use-new-run
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Successfully resolved issue by removing the flags: --cache-copy-layers and --single-snapshot, and adding the flag: --cleanup

Comment: `--single-snapshot` says "Take a single snapshot at the end of the build" which sounds like there are no intermediate layers to use as a cache, so it makes sense removing it would help.

Answer (score 0):

When we set --cache-repo as ECR repo url, kaniko push all layers to ecr repo as cache, if dockerfile has too many/multi-step instructions, this increases the ECR repo storage size. And for each build it pushes the cache to ecr repo.
Can we have option like if layer cache is present in ECR repo then do not push it again?

@Tom Saleeba @Andres Cabrera