# Kaniko with Remote ECR repo for --cache-repo

Tags: docker, build, cicd, kaniko

This is related to [Kaniko do not use cache options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75414242/kaniko-do-not-use-cache-options/78225047#78225047)

When we set --cache-repo as ECR repo url, kaniko push all layers to ecr repo as cache, if dockerfile has too many/multi-step instructions, this increases the ECR repo storage size. And for each build it pushes the cache to ecr repo. Can we have option like if layer cache is present in ECR repo then use that cache while building the image and do not push it again?

I am using below options to build image with kaniko:

> docker run gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest
> --context=/workspace/build --dockerfile=/workspace/build/{dockerfile} --destination={image_tag_version} --cache=true --cache-repo=84592232.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev-builds --use-new-run --cache-run-layers --cache-copy-layers --snapshot-mode=redo --cleanup --verbosity=info --log-timestamp

our build requirement is daily 20-30 build of different code languages.. ECR has the storage limit of 10000 tags for each repo. So limit exceeds within 2-3 days.

Can someone check this?